# Is there an arbitrary precision library in C or C++ with cdf?

Tags: linux, c++, c, math, statistics

I tried GNU Science library but its precision is limited to doubles. Other than implementing the thing myself, which I hope I wont have to do, is there a library that gets me the cumulative distribution function for the binomial distribution in C or C++ with arbitrary precision?